# Deserialize using generic class with generic list property

Tags: java, jackson

I cannot deserialize generic class after upgrade jackson to 2.8.8 version.
I use custom deserializer for DataJson and after upgrade jackson I get `JsonMappingException`

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.example.dto.ConcernData: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: {
  "type": {
    "name": "TYPE_NAME"
  },
  "people": [
    {"id": 1}
  ]
}; line: 6, column: 5] (through reference chain: com.example.dto.DataJson["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Last version of Jackson with which I was a able to deserialize `DataJson` is 2.6.7.

https://github.com/maselpopowo/JacksonDeserializerIssue

Comment: How does Jackson know about the existence of `CommonConcernData`?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I updated my code

Comment: Something still seems off - you're only passing a single argument to `constructParametericType`.  Can you please create a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), rather than pseudocode.

Comment: I create git repository https://github.com/maselpopowo/JacksonDeserializerIssue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in 2.8.8 if you define `DataJson` to extend the (generic) `BasicDataJson` with the same type `T`. E.g.

```
public class DataJson<T extends ConcernData> extends BasicDataJson<T>
```

instead of the raw type like `extends BasicDataJson`.

I noticed that it works with Jackson 2.6.x but not 2.7.x or 2.8.x. Take note of this paragraph in the release notes of Jackson 2.7 [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.7#fix-generic-type-resolution-mechanism)

> There are certain tricky edge cases that do not work.
>   Specifically, type variable aliasing (case where variable name like T
>   binds to different types at different points in hierarchy) is not
>   correctly resolved, as variable binding is constructed globally and
>   not hierarchically.